# ASP Classic/MSSQL records displaying in multiple tables, not in rows

Tags: sql-server, html-table, asp-classic

I'm working on my first ASP Classic app, it's just a simple one that adds data to a MSSQL database, and displays all the records on another page...

I have everything seemingly working, except when I go to the view page it displays all the records in their own table, instead of displaying as one table with a header row, and then multiple records in multiple rows.

I'm not looking for someone to solve it for me, that's not how I learn, but if someone could point me in the right direction, where I could figure it out I'd sure appreciate it!

Sample Code:

```
<table border="1"> 
<tr> 
<td><%=objRec.Fields("keyfield").Value%></td> 
<td><%=objRec.Fields("server_application").Value%></td> 
<td><%=objRec.Fields("environment").Value%></div></td> 
<div align="center"><%=objRec.Fields("ip_address").Value%></td> 
<td><%=objRec.Fields("url").Value%></td> 
<td><%=objRec.Fields("server_name").Value%></td> 
<td><%=objRec.Fields("obsolete").Value%></td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<% rownum = rownum + 1 
objRec.MoveNext 
Wend 
objRec.Close() 
Conn.Close() 
Set objRec = Nothing 
Set Conn = Nothing 
%>
```

Comment: Most probably you are adding the `<table>` and `</table>` inside the  loop which builds the table. You should do it outside.

Comment: [Display the Field Names and Field Values in an HTML Table](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_display.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it should be

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr> 
    <td>Key Field</td> 
    <td>Server Application</td> 
    <td>Field 3 header</td> 
    <td>Field 4 header</td> 
    <td>Field 5 header</td> 
    <td>Field 6 header</td> 
    <td>Field 7 header</td> 
    </tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <% Do while not objRec.EOF %>
    <tr> 
    <td><%=objRec.Fields("keyfield").Value%></td> 
    <td><%=objRec.Fields("server_application").Value%></td> 
    <td><%=objRec.Fields("environment").Value%></div></td> 
    <div align="center"><%=objRec.Fields("ip_address").Value%></td> 
    <td><%=objRec.Fields("url").Value%></td> 
    <td><%=objRec.Fields("server_name").Value%></td> 
    <td><%=objRec.Fields("obsolete").Value%></td> 
    </tr> 
    <% objRec.MoveNext()
    Loop %>
</tbody>
</table> 

<%    
objRec.Close() 
Conn.Close() 
Set objRec = Nothing 
Set Conn = Nothing 
%>
```

Comment: @user2548961: If the answer helped you to solve your problem, go ahead, click on the tick to accept it.